# Area formed by 3 points in vector

Tags: vectors

Why can we apply parallelogram law for finding area of a triangle if there are infinite vectors equivalent to those vectors representing the sides of triangle,Why did we specifically use the difference of any two coordinates as sides of our parallelogram...can't we use any other vector combination for that?

Comment: In what way does the parallelogram law give the area of a triangle?

Comment: Do you mean the vectors parallel to the vectors making up the sides of the triangle?

Comment: @Triatticus Yes

Comment: Well if you move all three vectors around they still form the same triangle as this is restricted by the lengths and directions of these vectors...there might be infinite parallel vectors but the triangle is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors are defined by their components,  so when we have V=<3, 5> we do not indicate an initial point or a terminal point. All it matters is the direction and the length of the vector. So if you move your vectors around you get the same result as long as you do not change the components.

You may think of a vector as a recipe for motion. V=<3, 5> means move to the right 3 units and move upward 5 units. You go from any initial point to a terminal point by following the recipe provided by components of the given vector.